# Connect Line Between 2 Elements - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, diagram

I'm currently working on a way to create a single-line diagram using Javascript. I'm currently able to connect two html elements using the following function:

```
adjustLine (from, to, line) {
  var fT = from.offsetTop  + from.offsetHeight/2;
  var tT = to.offsetTop      + to.offsetHeight/2;
  var fL = from.offsetLeft + from.offsetWidth/2;
  var tL = to.offsetLeft     + to.offsetWidth/2;

  var CA   = Math.abs(tT - fT);
  var CO   = Math.abs(tL - fL);
  var H    = Math.sqrt(CA*CA + CO*CO);
  var ANG  = 180 / Math.PI * Math.acos( CA/H );

  if(tT > fT){
      var top  = (tT-fT)/2 + fT;
  }else{
      var top  = (fT-tT)/2 + tT;
  }
  if(tL > fL){
      var left = (tL-fL)/2 + fL;
  }else{
      var left = (fL-tL)/2 + tL;
  }

  if(( fT < tT && fL < tL) || ( tT < fT && tL < fL) || (fT > tT && fL > tL) || (tT > fT && tL > fL)){
    ANG *= -1;
  }
  top-= H/2;

  line.style["-webkit-transform"] = 'rotate('+ ANG +'deg)';
  line.style["-moz-transform"] = 'rotate('+ ANG +'deg)';
  line.style["-ms-transform"] = 'rotate('+ ANG +'deg)';
  line.style["-o-transform"] = 'rotate('+ ANG +'deg)';
  line.style["-transform"] = 'rotate('+ ANG +'deg)';
  line.style.top    = top+'px';
  line.style.left   = left+'px';
  line.style.height = H + 'px';
}
```

The function takes 3 parameters:

- 1) the first html element
- 2) the second html element
- 3) the line that connects the elements.

This works fine and outputs the following result:

[image]

However, the lines that connect the html elements are a straight line, I would like to have a more natural flow for a diagram, something like the following:

[image]

Any advice on how I could go about doing this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit**

I'm using html2canvas to create an image of the generated output. This is my code:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('content');

html2canvas(myDiv, {useCORS: true, allowTaint : true}).then(function (canvas) {

            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
            var imgData2 = canvas2.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);

            var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', [HTML_Width, HTML_Height]);
            pdf.internal.scaleFactor = 30;
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, HTML_Width, HTML_Height);

            pdf.addPage();
            pdf.addImage(imgData2, 'PNG', 0, 0, HTML_Width_2, HTML_Height_2);

            pdf.save("my_file.pdf");
});
```

Comment: Could you upload rest of the code?

Comment: @JacekRojek sure, here's the code in CodePen: https://codepen.io/MejorCodigo/pen/YzXpmYY.

Comment: this looks overkill but I would go like this. Consider the somehow manhattan distance: x axis counts double. Then do Astar from point A to B. (this would favor going to the top first). Then for point C to B you have painted the canvas, A star will avoid crossing the line and should stay "next" to it. This is a random thought of 5min though

Comment: A* implementation would be overkill for this, but would definitely work.  Is there limitations on how many lines a single object would have?  How dynamic would this system need to be? Can user interaction move the elements around, updating the lines in realtime?  Are the number of connected elements all known upfront at once or dynamically added?

Comment: @Phaelaxz hi, each object is added dynamically to a `<div>`... using a json file I know how many elements should be printed and the parent/child of each element, also the user should not move the elements around thus the lines don't need to be updated in real time, and ideally there should be 2 lines per connection.

Comment: Why don't you use SVG ? do you accept a SVG answer ?

Comment: @MisterJojo sure, I'll accept it as an answer, I haven't though about using SVG's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So heree is my solution with SVG!

```js
const xmlns   = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
  ,   svgLink = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
  ,   elmSVG  = document.getElementById('elmSVG')
  ,   bot_inversor  = 80
  ,   top_fotovolta = 300
  ;
for (let i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
  let x = 10 + (i*60)
    , fotovolta = document.createElementNS(xmlns, 'use');

  fotovolta.setAttributeNS(svgLink, 'xlink:href', '#fotovoltaico');

  fotovolta.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', x);
  fotovolta.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', top_fotovolta);
  fotovolta.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '50');
  fotovolta.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '70'); 

  elmSVG.appendChild(fotovolta);

  adjustLines(i);
  }
function adjustLines(item)
  {
  let left = (item<2)    // the hard part...  
    , b1 = 25 + (item *60) + (left?0:20)
    , b2 = b1 + (left?20:-20)
    , a1 = 105 + (item *10) + (left?0:10)
    , a2 = a1 + (left?5:-5)
    , l1 = 50 + (left?item:3-item) *30
    , l2 = l1 + 10
    ;
  let jLine1 = document.createElementNS(xmlns, 'polyline');
  jLine1.setAttributeNS(null, 'points', `${b1},${top_fotovolta} ${b1},${bot_inversor+l1} ${a1},${bot_inversor+l1} ${a1},${bot_inversor}`);
  elmSVG.appendChild(jLine1);   

  let jLine2 = document.createElementNS(xmlns, 'polyline');
  jLine2.setAttributeNS(null, 'points', `${b2},${top_fotovolta} ${b2},${bot_inversor+l2} ${a2},${bot_inversor+l2} ${a2},${bot_inversor}`);
  elmSVG.appendChild(jLine2);   
  }
```

```css
#elmSVG {
  width: 250px;
  height: 380px;
  background-color: #b4f0f0;
  margin: 1em;
}
#elmSVG * {
  fill:none;
  stroke:#2f363d;
  stroke-width:2px;
}
.curveSVG {
  stroke-linecap:round;
}
```

```html
<h2>Connecting Lines</h2>

<svg id="elmSVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 250 380">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="inversor" viewBox="0 0 70 70">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="70" height="70" />
      <line x1="70" x2="0" y1="0" y2="70"  />
      <line x1="10" x2="30" y1="15" y2="15" />
      <line x1="10" x2="30" y1="20" y2="20"  />
      <path d="M 40,55 Q 45,45 50,55 T 60,55" class="curveSVG" />
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="fotovoltaico"  viewBox="0 0 50 70">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="70" />
      <line x1="0" x2="25" y1="0" y2="20"  />
      <line x1="50" x2="25" y1="0" y2="20"  />
    </symbol>
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#inversor" x="90"  y="10" width="70" height="70" />
</svg>
```

Comment: hi, this answer look suitable, however, I haven't gotten time to start implementing it, I'll try to implement it in the next couple of days and get back to you if any questions come up. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @BrianMoreno no problemo :-)

Comment: Hi @MisterJojo, I'm currently working on implementing this, so far it's working fine. The only problem is I'm using html2canvas to create an image but the SVG won't show in the output. Any recommendation? I've edited the question to give you an idea of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @BrianMoreno I have never been very comfortable with canvas, but I will see what I can do

Comment: Thanks for your help! :D

Comment: @BrianMoreno did you try my other solution below ?

Comment: @BrianMoreno don't you want to reward any of my ansers ? ( you have to done it manualy)

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't know you had to do it manually. I gave you the reward. :)

Answer (score 1):

other solution with `<canvas>`

```js
const eCanvas = document.getElementById('elmCanvas')
  ,   cCanvas = eCanvas.getContext('2d')
  ,   bot_inversor  = 80
  ,   top_fotovolta = 300
  ;

// set background color
cCanvas.fillStyle = 'rgb(178, 240, 240)'
cCanvas.fillRect(0, 0, eCanvas.width, eCanvas.height )

Draw_Inversor( cCanvas, (eCanvas.width/2 - 70/2), 10)

for (let i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
  Draw_Fotovoltaico( cCanvas, 10+(i*60), top_fotovolta );
  Draw_connectsLines( cCanvas, i, 4, (eCanvas.width/2), (10+(i*60)+25) );
  }

function Draw_Inversor( ctx, x, y )
  {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x+70, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y+70);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x+70, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x+70, y+70);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y+70);
  ctx.moveTo(x+10, y+15);
  ctx.lineTo(x+30, y+15);
  ctx.moveTo(x+10, y+20);
  ctx.lineTo(x+30, y+20);
  ctx.moveTo(x+50, y+55);
  ctx.arc(x+45, y+55, 5, 0, Math.PI, true);
  ctx.moveTo(x+60, y+55);
  ctx.arc(x+55, y+55, 5, 0, Math.PI, false);
  ctx.stroke();
  }
function Draw_Fotovoltaico( ctx, x, y )
  {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x+25, y+20);
  ctx.lineTo(x+50, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y+70);
  ctx.lineTo(x+50, y+70);
  ctx.lineTo(x+50, y);
  ctx.stroke();
  }
function Draw_connectsLines( ctx, no, maxOcc, topCenter, botCenter )
  {
  let mid   = maxOcc/2
    , left  = no < mid
    , decal = left ? no :(maxOcc/2)-no+1 
    , topL1 = 50+ (decal *30)
    , topL2 = topL1 +10
    , topX1 = topCenter + (left? -(mid-decal)*10 : +(mid-decal)*10 )
    , topX2 = topX1 +(left?+5:-5)
    , botX1 = botCenter + (left?-10:+10)
    , botX2 = botCenter + (left?+10:-10) 
    ;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(topX1, bot_inversor);
  ctx.lineTo(topX1, bot_inversor +topL1 );
  ctx.lineTo(botX1, bot_inversor +topL1 );
  ctx.lineTo(botX1, top_fotovolta );
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(topX2, bot_inversor);
  ctx.lineTo(topX2, bot_inversor +topL2 );
  ctx.lineTo(botX2, bot_inversor +topL2 );
  ctx.lineTo(botX2, top_fotovolta );
  ctx.stroke();
  }
```

```css
#elmCanvas {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="elmCanvas" width="250" height="400"></canvas>
```